# Telegram bot in python; Autodestruction

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to configure my bot with an autodestruction command, that will ban every member from the group that is not an admin. When i type a command in the group the bot doesn't reply, it responds only when i write directly to him, and when i try the autodestruction command, it gives this error:

```
update {'update_id': 967684662, 'message': {'caption_entities': [], 'message_id': 201, 'entities': [{'type': 'bot_command', 'offset': 0, 'length': 5}], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'text': '/pyro', 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'photo': [], 'channel_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'chat': {'username': 'khagnaccio', 'first_name': 'kernel', 'id': 5377477821, 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1661264074, 'new_chat_members': [], 'from': {'id': 5377477821, 'language_code': 'it', 'first_name': 'kernel', 'username': 'khagnaccio', 'is_bot': False}}} ha causato un errore There is no current event loop in thread 'Bot:5561807213:dispatcher'.
/home/elias/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py:575: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ChatMethods.get_participants' was never awaited
  self.logger.exception('An uncaught error was raised while handling the error.')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

here is the bot code:

```
import con as keys
import asyncio
from telegram.ext import *
import responses as r
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.types import (
    PeerChannel
)
import pyrogram
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import os, sys
import time

print("Iniziamo...")

def pyro_command(update, context):
    
    print('[+] scegli il gruppo dove vuoi bannare gli utenti:')
    i=0
    for g in groups:
        print('[' + str(i) + ']' + ' - '+ g.title )
        i+=1
 
    print('')
    g_index = input("inserisci il numero del gruppo scelto: ")
    target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
 
    print("Seleziono gli utenti...")
    time.sleep(1)
    all_participants = []
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False)
    print('[+] Banno gli utenti...')
    time.sleep(1)   
    print('[+] Utenti bannati.')

def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("INIZIALIZZAZIONE....")
    for x in range(1, 4):
        update.message.reply_text("Pyro Never Dies.")

def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Se hai bisogno di aiuto, chiedi a un Admin!")

def handle_message(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = r.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)

def error(update, context):
    print(f"update {update} ha causato un errore {context.error}")



try:
    api_id = "api id"
    api_hash = "api hash"
    phone = 'phone number'
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except KeyError:
    os.system('clear')
    print("Errore.")
client.connect()
print("Client creato e connesso....")
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    os.system('clear')
    client.sign_in(phone, input('[+] Enter the code: '))
 
os.system('clear')

updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context = True)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("pyro", pyro_command))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
dp.add_error_handler(error)
chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 900
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
         offset_date=last_date,
         offset_id=0,
         offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
         limit=chunk_size,
         hash = 0
     ))
chats.extend(result.chats)
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change `client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False)` to `await client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False)`, as that method is a coroutine method (`async def ...`). However, you can't use `await` within ordinary functions.

There are three directions that you can take to make this work and I'll list them in the order in which I think they are sensible:

1. Don't mix `telethon` and `python-telegram-bot`. You apparently want to leverage userbot functionality, so you'll have to use `telethon`. `telethon` can however also be used to write code for normal bots, so you don't really need to get ptb involved as well. Sticking to one framework should reduce the number of complications drastically.
2. Use v20.x of PTB. In v20 (currently in pre-release mode), PTB was switched to `asyncio` as well, so that it should be way easier to combine PTB and `telethon`.
3. Manage your own `asyncio` event loop and use things like `asyncio.loop.run_until_complete` to run telethons coroutine methods within the ordinary callback functions that you use in PTB v13.x

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: i don't know much about asyncio, how i am supposed to loop? do i have to async the function and the main and client._run_until_complete? i read that in and i tried, but it didn't worked.

Comment: if you're not familiar enough with asyncio to cook up a manual solution, I highly recommend to choose option 1 or 2

Comment: im not familiar also with PTB, this is my first telegram bot :)

Comment: i will try to rewrite the bot only with telethon, if i need something, i will write here :)